# How to add new relationship in spring data neo4j 4.1.2

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I already followed this [Tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/neo4j/posts/the-essence-of-spring-data-neo4j-4#what-next-).

I want to add new ingredient called Beef to the Meat category that already created by following tutorial above. Here is my code to add new ingredient :

```
    Category categoryMeat = categoryRepository.findByName("Meat");
    Ingredient ingredientBeef = ingredientRepository.findByName("Beef");
    ingredientBeef.setCategory(categoryMeat);
    ingredientRepository.save(ingredientBeef);
```

Then I pair beef with carrot:

```
    Pairing pairingNew = new Pairing();
    pairingNew.setFirst(ingredientBeef);
    pairingNew.setSecond(carrot);
    pairingNew.setAffinity("Delicious");
    pairingRepository.save(pairingNew);
```

Then I remove the beef using this code :

```
    Ingredient deletedBeef = ingredientRepository.findByName("Beef");
    ingredientRepository.delete(deletedBeef);
```

Then I try to add new ingredient using this code and pair lamb with carrot:

```
    Category newCategoryMeat = categoryRepository.findByName("Meat");
    Ingredient ingredientLamb = new Ingredient("Lamb");
    ingredientLamb.setCategory(newCategoryMeat);
    ingredientRepository.save(ingredientLamb);

    Pairing pairingNewLamb = new Pairing();
    pairingNewLamb.setFirst(ingredientLamb);
    pairingNewLamb.setSecond(carrot);
    pairingNewLamb.setAffinity("Delicious");
    pairingRepository.save(pairingNewLamb);
```

When I try to save new ingredient lamb, I get this error:

```
Error executing Cypher "Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound"; Code: Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound; Description: Relationship with id 6
```

How to fix it?

For your information: i'm using spring data neo4j 4.1.2 and neo4j community edition 3.0.6

Here's my pom dependency:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>   

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Which versions of SDN and Neo4j are you using?

Comment: @Luanne I'm using sdn 4.1.2 and neo4j community 3.0.6